# strpos() doesn't seem to be recognizing my the string I am using

Tags: php, strpos

I have the following string:

```
CAE33D8E804334D5B490EA273F36830A9849ACDF|xx|yy|46|13896|9550
```

which in the code below corresponds to `$track_matches[0][0]`.

The only constant-length field is the first (`CAE33D8E804334D5B490EA273F36830A9849ACDF`), which is 40 characters long. I am trying to get the values `xx` and `yy` which are an unknown length and value along with the rest of the column.

So I am trying something like this:

```
 $seperator= '|';
 $end_seed= strpos($track_matches[0][0], $seperator, 41 );
 $seeders[$i] =  substr($track_matches[0][0], 41, $end_seed - 41);
 $end_leech= strpos($track_matches[0][0], $seperator, $end_seed +1 );
 echo "end_seed" . $end_seed . " end_leach: " . $end_leech;
 $leechers[$i] =  substr($track_matches[0][0], $end_seed +1, $end_leech - $end_seed - 1);
```

The problem I am getting is the line `$end_leech=` doesn't seem to work properly (and doesn't recognize the `$seperator`) and retuns the entire line (`$track_matches[0][0]`) as it's value when `echo`'d while $end_seed returns the proper value. ... so what's going on why is this happening? howw do i fix it?

Comment: Why not [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)?

Comment: Why not just use `explode()`?

Comment: because , I forgot this function existed in php (still learning) copy as an answer and i will except ... god that's frustrating

Comment: chin up, learning is a joy, not frustration

Comment: @brendanmorrison The opposite `implode()` is also very useful for displaying arrays/rurning them into strings.

Comment: @h2ooooooo thanks i know... I use it earlier in the same script ... I'm not sure how I forgot explode, rattling .. I appreciate the input non-the less

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try :

```
$myString="CAE33D8E804334D5B490EA273F36830A9849ACDF|xx|yy|46|13896|9550";
$splitString=explode('|',$myString);
$xx=$splitString[1];
$yy=$splitString[2];
```

of course you can replicate manually with strpos, substr etc but will take more effort

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$temp = explode("|", $track_matches[0][0]);
```

That will return an array and you can then reference the vars as `$temp[1]` (xx) and `$temp[2]` (yy)